# mysqldump generating inconsistent dumps

Tags: mariadb

I cannot get mysqldump to generate a dump that will properly restore.  The dump is being generated to setup a new slave, but whenever the slave starts up, it gets foreign key constraint failures.

I'm generating the dump with slave positions and as a single transaction so that the dump is (allegedly) atomic, but when I essentially execute the following:

```
mysqldump \
    -h master
    --flush-logs --single-transaction --master-data \
    --apply-slave-statements \
    --databases my-db \
    | mysql -h slave
```

I get the following error when I "SHOW SLAVE STATUS":

```
Last_Errno: 1452
Last_Error: Error 'Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails ...
```

All of the tables use the InnoDB engine, and the foreign key is an integer.

Using MariaDB 10.3.

Comment: consider moving to dba.stackexchange.com

Comment: I've done so.  Thanks.  Is there some way of linking the two questions? https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/254829/mysqldump-generating-inconsistent-dumps

Comment: try `SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0` before doing operation reference: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5005388/cannot-add-or-update-a-child-row-a-foreign-key-constraint-fails

Comment: Unless I'm mistaken, disabling foreign key checks will simply cause invalid data to be written.